# Top city in each state in one query

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I'm having problem solving this query about how to get the highest city in each state based on their sales. Only the highest city in each state are selected. This is my code

```
SELECT c.STATE, C.CITY,  SUM(qty * saleprice) AS "TOTAL SALES"
FROM DWCUST C
INNER JOIN DWSALE S
ON C.DWCUSTID = S.DWCUSTID
GROUP BY c.STATE, C.CITY
ORDER BY 1;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which DB are you using? MySQL, Oracle, SQLServer, PostgreSQL, ...

Comment: Hi, Im currently using ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER.

Answer (score 0):

try this! (IN `SQL-SERVER`)

```
select * from 
(
SELECT c.STATE, C.CITY,TOTAL_SALES=row_number()over(partition by c.STATE order by  SUM(qty * saleprice))
FROM DWCUST C
INNER JOIN DWSALE S
ON C.DWCUSTID = S.DWCUSTID
GROUP BY c.STATE, C.CITY
)x1
where x1.TOTAL_SALES=1
```

Might work in oracle?

```
 select * from 
    (
    SELECT c.STATE, C.CITY,SUM(qty * saleprice) as x1,row_number()over(partition by c.STATE order by x1))TOTAL_SALES
    FROM DWCUST C
    INNER JOIN DWSALE S
    ON C.DWCUSTID = S.DWCUSTID
    GROUP BY c.STATE, C.CITY
    )x
    where x.TOTAL_SALES=1
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, i try in sql developer but its appear to be an error. Error at command line 3 column 35 : " FROM keyword not found where expected".

Comment: In Oracle the alias form `alias = value` is not present, you should change `TOTAL_SALES=row_number()over(partition by c.STATE order by  SUM(qty * saleprice))` to `row_number()over(partition by c.STATE order by  SUM(qty * saleprice)) TOTAL_SALES` (and I'm not sure about `order by  SUM(qty * saleprice)`)

Comment: Hi serpiton.  Your code works thanks.  But as you guess it the sum column are needed in the table.

Comment: Hi can i call you joker?  (i cant see your name) i try your new code but same error appear just like the first code you given

Comment: try using `CTE` and put the example in sqlfiddle.com

Comment: try posting some example data with output!